# Our Azure Dev-ops needs to be migrated to a new company after being acquired, any guidance what needs to be done?

Tags: azure-devops

We were in company A in Azure DevOps and now need to switch Azure DevOps over to company B ownership and accounts. We are hoping to find a process for migrating Azure DeOps between companies and keeping our projects data and mapping user accounts?